# How to call jar file function in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet

How to call jar file functions in javascript using applet tag?

please help anyone I am new to java. Kindly do the needful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi I am not asking about calling applet method from javascript. I am asking about sample.jar file function from javascript using applet tag. Then how this will become possible duplicate of that question. So don't mark like that BladeOrz.........

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result= document.appleNameInTag.getSomeMethod();
```

where

```
appleNameInTag  is  name of Applet
getSomeMethod   is method of applet
```

[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html)